# creat button for change background color

Tags: javascript

I want to create two buttons in HTML called 'green' and 'red'. When clicking on them, the style `"background-color: {COLOR-SELECTED}"` should be changed dynamically.

```js
var verde = document.getElementById('verde')
var vermelho = document.getElementById('vermelho')
var body = document.querySelector('body')

function verde() {
  body.className = "verde";
}

function vermelho() {
  body.className = "vermelho";
}
```

```css
.verde {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.vermelho {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="verde" onclick="verde ()" id="verde"></button>
  <button class="vermelho" onclick="vermelho ()" id="vermelho"></button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `classList` API to add or remove a class to body.
More info [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
function verde () {

    body.classList.remove('vermelho');
    body.classList.add('verde');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few changes I've made:

1. Remove the space between the function name and the `()` in the HTML.
2. Removed the first two lines of the javascript – you never use these variables.
3. Changed `querySelector` to `getElementsByTagName`, which creates a list of elements, so that you can select the first one using `[0]`

The snippet below should work as expected:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

function verde() {
  body.className = "verde";
}

function vermelho() {
  body.className = "vermelho";
}
```

```css
.verde {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.vermelho {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<body class="none">
  <button class="verde" onclick="verde()" id="verde"></button>
  <button class="vermelho" onclick="vermelho()" id="vermelho"></button>
</body>
```